# Where can I view an online digitized Slavita shas?

Tags: shas

Where can I view an online digitized [Slavuta Shas](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/501896/the-slavuta-shas.html)? I want to see which commentaries it contained.

Comment: Could you explain what a slavuta shas is

Comment: This question is referring to the Slavita Shas published by the Shapira family - became involved in a famous dispute with the Romm family in the early 1800s over publishing rights as mentioned here: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/דפוס_סלאוויטא

Answer (score 1):

This question is referring to the Slavita Shas published by the Shapira family. This was the subject of a famous dispute with the Romm family in the early 1800s over publishing rights - [see this Hebrew Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90).

Digital scans of at least a portion of the tractates can be found online such as [Bava Basra](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990020919840205171/NLI), [Sanhedrin](https://viewer.rsl.ru/ru/rsl01006773314) and [Makkos](https://viewer.rsl.ru/ru/rsl01006773316).

Links to several digitized masechtos are also available resulting from [this search here](https://search.rsl.ru/en/search#digitalAvail=digitized&q=%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90%20%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99).

Comment: Thank you! How did you search the last one? Do you know Russian?

Comment: I searched with the Hebrew search term בסלאוויטא תלמוד בבלי. I don't know Russian.  I did just modify the final URL above to point to the English version of the search page, but much of the descriptive content still appears in Russian.  After I found some of the initial material on the National Library of Israel site, I saw links there that pointed me to the Russian State Library site.